# header/footer terminal display

Tags: python

How do I create a python script where there is a static header and footer like in this image?

[image: GNU nano]

Comment: See the [`curses` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) for python. Example:

```
import curses

myscreen = curses.initscr()
curses.start_color()
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
y,x = myscreen.getmaxyx()
myscreen.addstr("Python curses in action!", curses.color_pair(1))
myscreen.move(y -1,0)
myscreen.addstr("Python curses in action!", curses.color_pair(1))
myscreen.refresh()
myscreen.getch()

curses.endwin()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Curses, or ncurses with python:

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html